# How to manipulate a DOM on a particular page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have a question, how to manipulate a DOM object on a particular page. What i'm trying to do is to open a pop-up page and then manipulate an object over there.

The following code manipulates the object on initial page:

```
cuteLittleWindow = window.open("/calendar/view.html", "littleWindow", "location=no,width=320,height=200"); 
$('.navbar-inner').hide();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
$(cuteLittleWindow.document).find('.navbar-inner').hide();
```

You don't have to include jQuery on the page in the cuteLittleWindow. But be sure to have both page served from the same domain. This especially means that you cannot test in `file://`.

Answer (score 1):

Not too difficult:

```
$(cuteLittleWindow.document)...
```

should do it as long as the opened document is **on the same domain** as the domain the originator is running in.

Comment: jQuery is a property of the document?